# Fetching Objects of object from API in React JS

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, visual-studio

I hope you are all fine, I am working on my project, I got some real issue while fetching my API. Actually, I am getting Student data from one of my EndPoint in spring boot and that data is in objects of an object like shown below;

```
    {
  "stdId": 22,
  "stdFirstName": "feezan",
  "stdLastName": "khattak",
  "stdPhone": "3984729347",
  "stdRollNo": "1714-17",
  "semester": {
    "semesterId": 2,
    "semester": 2
  },
  "address": {
    "addressId": 27,
    "mohallah": "hajiAbad",
    "city": "Shaidu",
    "district": "nsr",
    "provience": "kpk"
  }
}
```

I get this data from one of my endpoint like `http://localhost:8080/students/getstudent/22`
I can access stdFirstName, stdLastName, etc, But When I try to access the semester or address it given me an error, you can't access the semester from undefined. The react code are the following;

```
// Main return statements
    return isEmpty || isLoading ? (
        <span>Data is Loading.....</span>
    ) : (
        <div className={viewStudentStyle.outerDiv}>
            <div className={viewStudentStyle.innerDiv}>
                {(console.log(singleStd), console.log(typeof singleStd))}
                <span>Student DB id: </span> <span>{singleStd.stdId}</span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className={viewStudentStyle.innerDiv}>
                <span>Student Name: </span>
                <span>
                    {singleStd.stdFirstName} {singleStd.stdLastName}
                </span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className={viewStudentStyle.innerDiv}>
                <span>Student RollNo: </span>
                <span>{singleStd.stdRollNo}</span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className={viewStudentStyle.innerDiv}>
                <span>Student Semester: </span> <span>{singleStd.semester.semester}</span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className={viewStudentStyle.innerDiv}>
                <span>Student Phone Number: </span> <span>{singleStd.stdPhone}</span>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div className={viewStudentStyle.innerDiv}>
                <span>Student Address: </span>
                <span>
                {singleStd.address.mohallah}, {singleStd.address.city},
                {singleStd.address.district}, {singleStd.address.provience}
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the method from which I accessed data from the endpoint;

```
const loadStudent = async () => {
        await axios
            .get(`http://localhost:8080/students/getstudent/${props.stdId}`)
            .then((res) => res.data)
            .then((data) => {
                if (data !== "undefined") {
                    setSingleStd(data);
                    setIsEmpty(false);
                    setIsLoading(false);
                }
            });
    };
```

I call this method inside the UseEffect like;

```
// UseEffect
    useEffect(() => {
        loadStudent();
    }, [props.stdId]);
```

I hope! I try my best to make my Idea clear
Thanks in advance **:)**

Comment: don't see any problems, it's just when you try to access the object in the object ?

Comment: can you please include how you are initializing `singleStd` state?

Comment: it's `const [singleStd, setSingleStd] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 0):

No problem found in your code.
Look at the [running example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-pike-dvd8u?file=/src/App.js)  extracted from your code

Comment: You are right bro, but when it comes to fetching from the endpoint it given a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem it is the backend problem, I use `fetchType.LAZY` When I update it to;

```
fetch=FetchType.EAGAR
```

It is now working for me.
Thank you All of You ***:)***